# Multiplot Animation

Tags: python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I am working on a project and I wanted to animate some of my results. For my project there is lots of computation done but there is one parameter that I would like to vary.

I have made up some mock code to illustrate my question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
alpha = np.linspace(1, 10, 50)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x * x
for i in range(len(alpha)):
    plt.plot(x, alpha[i] * y)
    plt.title("Alpha = " + str(alpha[i]))                                                              
    plt.xlim(0, 10)
    plt.ylim(1, 100)
    plt.savefig("./animation_test/" + str(i) + "_Alpha=" + str(alpha[i]) + ".png")
    plt.close()
```

This leaves me with a my images in a folder I made called animation_test. Now I was just going to run something in my bash terminal like

```
$convert -delay 50 * test.gif
```

to make a simple little animated gif but the ordering in my terminal is a little funny

```
0_Alpha=1.0.png
10_Alpha=2.83673469388.png
11_Alpha=3.02040816327.png
.
.
.
19_Alpha=4.48979591837.png
1_Alpha=1.18367346939.png
20_Alpha=4.67346938776.png
21_Alpha=4.85714285714.png
.
.
.
```

Now in my Finder they are listed in the correct order. Is there a better way to label these files or even a better way to do the animation as a whole? The final product doesn't have to be a .gif, just something I can play.

Comment: It sounds like you just want something like `filename = "/path/{:02}_Alpha={:0.3f}.png".format(i, alpha[i])`  That way your filenames will be `00_Alpha...`, `01_Alpha...`, `02_Alpha...`, etc, and will sort properly.  (Also, if you have more than 100 steps, you'll wan to use `"{:03}"` instead of `"{:02}"`.) Alternatively, you can use matplotlib's animation module and output a gif or video directly.

Comment: +1 what @JoeKington said about using the animation module.  Don't re-invent the wheel;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

1. use human sorting
2. prepend zeros to your numbers in order to have a fixed number of digits. 
   Example, if you have labels like:

   - 1-file.ext
   - 2-file.ext
     ...
   - 99-file.ext

   you want to have something like:

   - 01-file.ext
   - 02-file.ext
     ...
   - 99-file.ext